# Django - change min_length in form __init__?

Tags: django, forms, multi-model-forms

Is there any way, to change the field's *min_length* argument inside form constructor?
That doesn't work:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CreateTeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['primary_color'].min_length = 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the field's `validators` attribute in the `__init__` method.

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    primary_color = forms.CharField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # get all the validators on the field which are not MinLengthValidator
        validators = [v for v in self.fields['primary_color'].validators if not isinstance(v, MinLengthValidator)]
        min_length = 10
        validators.append(MinLengthValidator(min_length))
        self.fields['primary_color'].validators = validators
```